# Binding autofac with webapi using generic repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to use autofac with a repository and I am trying to add a little generics to try reducing the amount of duplicate code I am writing.However I am going round in circles trying to get autofac to work for me

So I created a domainservice and interface that handles our the standard crud operations

```
public class DomainService<T>:IDomainService<T>
{
    protected readonly IDomainService<T> Repository;

    public DomainService(IDomainService<T> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }



    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
    {
        return Repository.GetQueryable();
    }

    public virtual Task<T> Add(T entity)
    {
       return Repository.Add(entity);
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface IDomainService<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQueryable();
    Task<T> Add(T entity);
    Task<bool> Delete(T entity);
    Task<T> Update(T entity);
    Task<T> GetById(int id);
    Task<T> GetByUID(Guid id);
}
```

I am using my repo is nothing special

```
public class SkillRepository : DomainService<Skill>, ISkill
{
    private DataContext _db = new DataContext();
    private readonly ILogger _log = null;

    public SkillRepository(IDomainService<Skill> repository, ILogger log) : base(repository)
    {
        _log = log;
    }
}
```

Finally where I wire up autofac:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the Web API controllers.
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Register other dependencies.
builder.Register(c => new Logger()).As<ILogger>().InstancePerApiRequest();

builder.RegisterType<SkillRepository>()
    .As<IDomainService<Skill>>()
    .As<ISkill>()
    .InstancePerRequest();

// Build the container.
var container = builder.Build();

// Create the depenedency resolver.
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

My web api controller looks like

```
public class SkillsController : BaseController<Skill>
{
    private readonly ISkill _skillRepository;

    public SkillsController(SkillRepository skillRepository) : base(skillRepository)
    {
        _skillRepository = skillRepository;
    }
}
```

BaseController

```
public abstract class BaseController<TEntity> : ApiController
    where TEntity : new()
{
    protected readonly IDomainService<TEntity> DomainService;

    protected BaseController(IDomainService<TEntity> domainService)
    {
        DomainService = domainService;
    }
```

I get an exception:

> "None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'Api.EndPoints.Skills.SkillsController' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters:\ \ Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Domain.Repository.SkillRepository skillRepository' of constructor
>   'Void .ctor(Domain.Repository.SkillRepository)'."

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot resolve the dependency because it's looking for the concrete type but you never registered `SkillsRepository` as that.  Now you could change the registration to register the concrete type but that wouldn't be the best approach.

A better approach is to register SkillsRepository as its interfaces:

```
builder.RegisterType<SkillRepository>()
    .As<ISkillsRepository>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

And define `ISkillsRepository` to inherit all the other interfaces like `ISkill` that you want.

```
public interface ISkillsRepository : ISkill, IDomainService<Skill> { }
```

**Don't register objects as concrete types and don't depend on concrete types in constructors.**

```
  public SkillsController(ISkillRepository skillRepository) : 
      base(skillRepository) ...
```

If you use concrete types as dependencies you create classes that cannot be tested using mocking frameworks.

Your use of `SkillRepository : DomainService<Skill>, ISkill` is perplexing too. Why is it both a skill and a domain service for skills? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your detailed explanation. It sounds like I am doing things slightly wrong. I have updated the above codes domain service to try show a little more what I am trying to do. Essentially I was trying to use DomainService as a way from me having to implement IDomainService<T> on every repository. As the code is the same and boring to write for every repo. Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes sense but you may be better off using Composition rather than Inheritance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Also, when you avoid 'Fat Controllers' (which is generally the right thing to do), you rarely need a base class for your controllers.

Comment: Thanks again Ian. I will take a look into composition...hopefully not difficult to use over inheritance

Comment: Ok sorry for so many questions. Where should I be using Composition rather than Inheritance in my SkillRepository? I have only really used inheritance so I don't really know the best approach while trying to use a repository

Comment: If each Controller is just exposing the same actions, all from BaseController you are probably fine as-is. Although a simpler structure might be to take the {type} as a path parameter and then have just one controller into which you inject all domain services (IEnumerable<...>) and you pick the correct type by name.  That way you can add new services without any changes to your controller code. Using Assembly registration you can register all domain services in one line too.

Answer (score 1):

Exception clearly states:

> Cannot resolve parameter 'Domain.Interfaces.ISkill skillRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Domain.IDomainService`1[Model.Skill], Domain.Interfaces.ISkill)'.

You have only `IDomainService` registered. But no `ISkill` (the line is commented).

Also why does the ctor require 2 parameters? `SkillRepository` implements both `IDomainService<Skill>` and `ISkill` so you should be able to pass it along:

```
public SkillsController(SkillRepository skillRepository) : base(skillRepository)
```

P.S.

I'd name it this way:

```
public class SkillRepository : ISkillRepository, IDomainService<Skill>
```

And I prefer everything to be either plural (SkillsControllers, SkillsRepository) or everything singular (SkillController, SkillRepository).

Comment: Hi @abatishchev I made a modification to the above codes global.asax. Can you spot what is wrong? I still havent manged to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should first sort out names for your classes which is making it hard to understand the code itself. secondly your repository is implementing domain service interface and ISkill and things like that is adding more confusion. i am pretty sure if you organise your classes properly then you will find solution to your problem. 
For instance ApiController should use domain service, domain service should use repository and repository should deal with enties.

```
public class SkillsDomainService:ISkillsDomainService
{
  public void AddSkill(string name){}
  public void DeleteSkillById(int id){}
  ..... etc
}

public class Repository:IRepository
{
   public T Get(int id){}
  public IEnumerable<T>GetAll(){}
}
```

Then you need to bind your interfaces to concrete classed in ioc. things should work that way i am pretty sure.