# autofac binding to a repository that inherits a base repo

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am trying to configure autofac with my generic repository 
I am using WebApi 2.2 and trying to create a generic controller and generic repository to do the CRUD operations.

I did ask this question but I think I may have over complicated the question [Binding autofac with webapi using generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321195/binding-autofac-with-webapi-using-generic-repository)

I have setup my projects with the following configuration

global.asax

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Register the Web API controllers.
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Register other dependencies.
    builder.Register(c => new Logger()).As<ILogger>().InstancePerApiRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<SkillRepository>()
        .As<IDomainService<Skill>>()
        .As<ISkill>()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    // Build the container.
    var container = builder.Build();

    // Create the depenedency resolver.
    var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

My controller

```
  public class SkillsController : BaseController<Skill>
    {
        private readonly ISkill _skillRepository;

        public SkillsController(SkillRepository skillRepository) : base(skillRepository)
        {
            _skillRepository = skillRepository;
        }
```

The repository

```
public class SkillRepository : DomainService<Skill>,ISkill
 {
     private DataContext _db = new DataContext();
     //private readonly ILogger _log = null;


    public SkillRepository(IDomainService<Skill> repository): base(repository)
    {

    }
```

interface

```
public interface ISkill
    {}
```

The domain service

```
  public class DomainService<T>:IDomainService<T>
    {
        protected readonly IDomainService<T> Repository;

        public DomainService(IDomainService<T> repository)
        {
            Repository = repository;
        }
```

The domains interface

```
 public interface IDomainService<T>
    {
        Task<T> Add(T entity);
        Task<bool> Delete(T entity);
        Task<T> Update(T entity);
  }
```

Why when I try call my controller do I get an error

> "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'SkillsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor."

Is there something stupid I am doing wrong here with my setup?

Comment: Instead of reposting your question, please revise the original one. You're only cluttering SO and confusing potential helpers.

Comment: @PeterLillevold I have closed it