# Autofac - Register generic constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am trying to register a Generic component with Autofac. The problem I am having is similar to the one in the link below(the error message is the same).
[Binding autofac with webapi using generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321195/binding-autofac-with-webapi-using-generic-repository)

I am using an onion architecture (http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). The DbContexts are in a separate layer, while the business layer is the one that will get data and do various things related to the business rules. Upper layers would only be aware of the interface IBaseDbManager. I have a vertical layer which takes care of resolving the dependencies.

Down below an example of the code and the Autofac configuration I have:

BUSINESS CLASS:

```
public class BaseDbManager<TContext> : IBaseDbManager where TContext : DbContext, IBaseContext
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    public BaseDbManager(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Partner GetPersonInfo(Expression<Func<Person,bool>> predicate)
    {
        var person = _context.Persons.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        return person;
    }
}
```

BUSINESS INTERFACE:

```
public interface IBaseDbManager
{
    Partner GetPersonInfo(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate);
}
```

DB CONTEXT:

```
   [Database]
    public class BaseContext : DbContext, IBaseContext
    {
        public BaseContext()
            : base((string) ConnectionHelper.BaseConnectionString())
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<BaseContext>(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

CONTEXT INTERFACE:

```
public interface IBaseContext
{
    DbSet<Partner> Partners { get; set; }
}
```

AUTOFAC MODULE:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<BaseContext>().As<IBaseContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(BaseDbManager<>)).As<IBaseDbManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

The problem is that Autofac does not know how to resolve IBaseDbManager without a parameterless constructor. I need TContext to be resolved by Autofac. How do you configure Autofac to resolve these scenarios? I tried registering as generic and based on the constructor and it didn't work either. If I add new() to the constraint and create an instance inside a parameterless constructor, then it works... I dont want to resolve it this way.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have more than one TContext object type in operation i take it? Why does TContext need to be generic?

Comment: @Derek: I have two objects that match the TContext constraint (BaseContext  and FakeBaseContext). BaseContext queries the database and FakeBaseContext uses fake data specifically created for unit testing. Autofac should resolve TContext as BaseContext for the API and Fake BaseContext for the unit testing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking several sections of the Autofac documentation, I found the registration piece that in conjunction to Steven's approach allowed Autofact to properly resolve the dependencies (see link below):

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html?highlight=WithParameter

The module registration I end-up coding is the following:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<BaseContext>()
           .As<IBaseContext>()
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterType<BaseDbManager<BaseContext>>().As<IBaseDbManager>()
           .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(BaseContext), new BaseContext()))
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

Additional feed back would be appreciated. I will continue refactoring my code as I think it can improve.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that Autofac does not know how to resolve IBaseDbManager without a parameterless constructor.

That's not the problem. The constructor is not the problem here, Autofac doesn't lay any constraints on your constructors.

The problem here is that given the open-generic `BaseDbManager<T>`, Autofac has no idea what closed-generic version of it to create, since the given `IBaseDbManager` abstraction is non-generic. It can't infer the generic types for you.

There are several solutions, but since the number of different context types in your application will most likely be very limited (often just 1), it makes the most sense to specify this context type in your registration. For instance:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(BaseDbManager<BaseContext>)).As<IBaseDbManager>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

If `BaseContext` is your only type of context it even makes more sense to make the `BaseDbManager<T>` non-generic, since making it generic only makes sense if you are actually planning to vary the type argument `T`.

> I have two objects that match the TContext constraint (BaseContext and FakeBaseContext). BaseContext queries the database and FakeBaseContext uses fake data specifically created for unit testing.

This doesn't seem like a valid reason to have another context class; a context is the definition of a set of entities; during testing, you have this same set of entities.

Comment: This was exactly my thoughts In the comments above, there is no requirement to have a generic dbcontext.

Comment: @Derek: Agreed. I didn't look at the comments before. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was just agreeing with your answer my friend. up voted it.

Comment: @Derek: I know :) But I had to comment about my update. It would be easy for the OP to miss it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Steven. I already tried your suggestion and it does not make any difference. I get the same error if I register the types either via RegisterGeneric, RegisterType, lambda and constructor: "None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'BaseDbManager`1[BaseContext]' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'BaseContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(BaseContext)'."

Comment: @Steven: I will try refactoring my code accordingly to use the same context as you mention. It will definitely make things easier.

Comment: @Charles: You never registered the `BaseContext` as service: you only registered `IBaseContext`.

Comment: @Steven: I just tried your suggestion and it didn't make a difference. Same error message. I will simplify my code in the upcoming days and post an update. I needed to refocus on other matters.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for your comments, they guide me in the right direction. See the solution above.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks for your comments, I will continue to work on a better solution.